# Understanding how actually drawRect or drawing coordinates work in Android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-canvas

I am trying to draw a rectangle over a canvas and I am facing troubles to understand the in-depth of rectangle draw of Android. I've read tutorials and every possible but I am stuck.

Here in the image , the red rectangle is my target.
[image]

Irrespective of any rectangle size I need to draw the red rectangle bit above the base and in the middle of the rectangle. The worst nightmare I am facing here is understanding the X,Y Width and Height coordinates.

Can anyone explain how that math works, sometime we go up , Y reaches to very small but same width coordinates are higher. And I am never able to justify red inner rectangle properly.In some screen it works well in some other it fails. The red rectangle sometimes come out of the parent rectangle.

**Agenda is to understand how coordinates work and ensure the integrity of inner red rectangle**

It'll be great to get an explanation based on an example. I am using-

```
void drawRect(float left, float top, float right, float bottom, Paint paint)
```

to drawing the rectangle

Comment: Rect(topleftx,toplefty,bottomrightx,bottomrighty)

Comment: I know these parameters but I am unable to understanding X , Y values , how to set it .. any example explanation will help

Comment: @JRowan among the rectangle posted by me , where does these param value sets ??

Comment: x=0 and y=0 at the topleft of the canvas, and the bottom right of the canvas is x = canvas.getWidth() and y = canvas.getHeight()

Comment: is that exactly how the rectangles look with the coordinates at the corners like that, is this a question out of a book or something

Comment: its not a book question , I experimented these rectangles on Nexus...

Comment: Thanks @AbhishekChoudhary for putting up this question. I am under stress understanding the same

Answer (score 16, accepted):

X runs horizontally, from left to right. Y runs vertically, from top to bottom. It's exactly the same as on your graphics. So (0/0) is at top left.

When you go "up" Y will of course get smaller, as it grows from top to bottom.

You have to pay attention to laying out elements like ListViews, these will give a partial (or new, you cannot tell) canvas to your views that are drawn. These views will have 0x0 at **their own** top/left position. If you need the absolute you have to subsequently call `View.getLocationOnScreen()` and calculate offsets yourself.

Comment: meredrica : these values are in pixels?

Answer (score 45):

**`canvas.drawRect(left,top,right,bottom,paint);`**

In this

1. left: distance of the left side of rectangular from left side of
   canvas.
2. top:Distance of top side of rectangular from the top side of
   canvas
3. right:distance of the right side of rectangular from left side of
   canvas.
4. bottom: Distance of the bottom side of rectangle from top side of canvas.

Comment: I think 2 and 4 are incorrect. They need to be:

2. top: Distance of TOP side of rectangular from the top side of canvas
4. bottom: Distance of the BOTTOM side of rectangle from top side of canvas.

Comment: savan : are these values in pixels?

Comment: Simple and perfect explanation. Exactly what I needed to really understand this.

Comment: That's what i needed

Answer (score 30):

This will make sense.

```
float left = 100, top = 100; // basically (X1, Y1)

float right = left + 100; // width (distance from X1 to X2)
float bottom = top + 100; // height (distance from Y1 to Y2)
```

Thus

```
RectF myRectum = new RectF(left, top, right, bottom);
canvas.drawRect(myRectum, myPaint);
```

Comment: I think that Rectangle variable name is the funniest thing I've ever seen on StackOverflow. XD

Answer (score 2):

Wish my note as below help you understand the relativity belong rect, canvas and view.

```
/**
 * Rect holds four integer coordinates for a rectangle.
 * The rectangle is represented by the coordinates of its 4 edges (left, top, right bottom).
 * These fields can be accessed directly. Use width() and height() to retrieve the rectangle's width and height.
 *
 * Note that the right and bottom coordinates are exclusive.
 * This means a Rect being drawn untransformed onto a Canvas will draw into the column and row described by its left and top coordinates
 * , but not those of its bottom and right.
 *
 * With regard to calling to Canvas#drawRect(left,top,right,bottom,paint)
 *
 * left: Distance of the left side of rectangle from left side of canvas.
 * top: Distance of top side of rectangle from the top side of canvas
 * right: Distance of the right side of rectangle from left side of canvas.
 * bottom: Distance of the bottom side of rectangle from top side of canvas.
 * __________________________________
 *|
 *|
 *|   __l_______________________r__
 *|  |         view group A        |
 *| t|  0______________________w   |
 *|  |  | **** view group B *** |  |
 *|  |  | **** canvas of B **** |  |
 *|  |  | ********************* |  |
 *|  |  | ********************* |  |
 *|  |  | ********************* |  |
 *|  |  | ***** __________ **** |  |
 *|  |  | *****|## rect ##|**** |  |
 *|  |  | *****|##########|**** |  |
 *|  |  | *****|##########|**** |  |
 *|  |  | *****|##########|**** |  |
 *|  |  | *****|##########|**** |  |
 *|  |  | ***** ---------- **** |  |
 *|  |  | ********************* |  |
 *| b|  h-----------------------   |
 *|  |                             |
 *|  |                             |
 *|   -----------------------------
 *|
 * -----------------------------------
 *
 * 1. l, t, r, b are coordinates of view group B (PastryChart) relative to view group A (parent of PastryChart).
 * 2. The size of canvas of B is same as the size of the view group B
 *    , which means canvas of B is a canvas which the view group B is rendered to.
 * 3. The coordinates of rect is relative to a canvas, here is the canvas of B
 *    , which means the coordinates of rect going to represent child of view group B are relative to the canvas of B.
 *    ex. for a rect holding left = 0, the position of its left is located on the same position of the left of view group B
 *    ex. for a rect holding right = w, the position of its right is located on the same position of the right of view group B
 *    ex. for a rect holding top = 0, the position of its top is located on the same position of the top of view group B
 *    ex. for a rect holding bottom = h, the position of its bottom is located on the same position of the bottom of view group B
 * 4. The rect is used to stored the child measurement computed in measure pass
 *    for forward positioning child view (PastryView) in the layout pass taken by parent view (PastryChart).
 * 5. All of them are in pixels (px)
 */
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is my approach simple and easy

```
            int x = 100;  //position coordinate from left
            int y = 100;  //position coordinate from top
            int w = 100; //width of the rectangle
            int h = 100; //height of the rectangle
            drawRectangle(x, y, w, h, canvas, paint);
```

and here is my function

```
    public void drawRectangle(int left, int top, int right, int bottom, Canvas canvas, Paint paint) {
    right = left + right; // width is the distance from left to right
    bottom = top + bottom; // height is the distance from top to bottom
    canvas.drawRect(left, top, right, bottom, paint);
}
```

it works pretty well