# Not able to align drawable rectangle coordinates according to given text in android?

Tags: android, android-canvas, android-drawable, android-bitmap

I want to draw a rectangle as a transparent canvas on my given `text` as following image:
[image]

I am using following code to draw the transparent rectangle but not able to understand the coordinates position. I tried a lot of time but it's not working.

```
canvas.drawRect(left,top,right,bottom,paint);
```

Here is my code:

```
Paint paint = new Paint();
paint.setAntiAlias(true);
paint.setColor(Color.WHITE);
paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
paint.setTextSize(40);
paint.setShadowLayer(2.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, Color.BLACK);
paint.setAlpha(255);
rectPaint.setAlpha(100);
canvas.drawText("$250", 20, 400, paint);
canvas.drawBitmap(bitmapImage, 490, 55, null);
canvas.drawRect(0, 100, 300, 400, rectPaint);
```

What would be the value of rest of the coordinates in `drawRect` method to align it as given `coordinates` of `text`. Right now I am using

```
canvas.drawRect(0, ? , ? , ?, rectPaint);
```

Comment: drawRect(float left, float top, float right, float bottom, Paint paint) -- best to make the rectangle not transparent so at least you can see it on screen and play around with position to understand it better

Comment: I can see the rectangle on my screen but not able to set it on the correct position. I have already played with it for almost one hour :(

Comment: @Tasos can you please look at the Eidt-1 section

Comment: here is some help to understand how position works -- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19464962/understanding-how-actually-drawrect-or-drawing-coordinates-work-in-android

Comment: Actually I followed it but location is not changing as per suggestion. I don't know why. BTW I tried your coordinates and it gave me this:
http://i.imgur.com/Uwhbb2U.png

Comment: BTW  canvas.drawRect(0, 350, 140, 420, rectPaint); works for me. I will Add my answer with better understanding.

Comment: canvas position also acts as the size by the sounds of it. you can also do a drawable rectangle shape -- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10124919/can-i-draw-rectangle-in-xml

Comment: Yes, But it was not possible in my situation because I am using Picasso transformation to add new Image

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `Paint.getTextBounds()` method for this.

> getTextBounds(String text, int start, int end, Rect bounds)
>
> Return in bounds (allocated by the caller) the smallest rectangle that
>   encloses all of the characters, with an implied origin at (0,0).

This will give you the `Rect` that you want, you then need to offset this `Rect` with the coordinates that you supplied with the `drawText` call.